# Recovering a Windows XP system gives error 0x0000007b in the BSOD

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-xp, drivers, bsod

So... I have a bit of a problem.

An old computer from a client with a Windows XP broke down (PSU or Mother Board) and there is a newer machine where that system can work. However, I cannot access the system anymore. I have got the **BSOD 0x0000007b**. This could mean there is an issue with drivers after swapping a disk like that.

So I need help to know how I can install the default IDE driver without being able to boot (safe mode doesn't work either).

Is it possible that I can connect the disk to another PC as external and do some magic on the files?

I must not format the disk! There is software and very important drivers for the machine connected to it which I have not the installation files.

Comment: You might possibly be able to convert the disk to a virtual machine.  There are old versions of Vcenter around (need to search) that might convert the machine.  Then the host VMware drivers would be used

Comment: Some (booting) issues with Windows cannot be resolved no matter what you do.  Your going to have a lot of difficult trying to boot into Windows XP on another machine.  Windows XP was designed to be portable.

Comment: This ^^^with a correction: Windows XP was NOT designed to be portable. Yes, there's a very good chance of recovering personal files. Software is irrelevant as always as it can and should be reinstalled or installed in the new machine. Drivers even more irrelevant because they WERE for the motherboard that no longer is, it's a pointless exercise and that machine should have been upgraded a long time ago (Windows XP is out of support for almost a decade, any attempt to use online is asking for serious problems).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am here to make your day! Read carefully and you will be soon running your museum piece XP os on a different (& compatible) motherboard. Here we go:

1. Make a Hiren's v15.2 boot CD (alternatively Ultimate Boot CD 4 Windows)
2. Boot with Hiren > Mini Windows XP
3. HBCD menu > Registry > “Fix hard disk controller (fix_hdc.cmd)”
4. Press T and tell the program where your Windows folder is (typically `C:\Windows`)
5. M > reboot > BOOM!!
6. You will need to re-activate XP license through Microsoft's phone automated system

Great tutorial with photos can be found here: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/move-windows-xp-hard-drive-or-change-motherboard-without-getting-blue-screen-of-death/2/

And remember, do not buy in Amazon!
Buy physically in your neighbourhood shops or in specialized internet shops.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This worked when moving the XP system to a virtual machine. I couldn't find the tool to FixHDC on the new Hiren's CD, but ver 15.2 from year 2012 has it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `BSOD 0x0000007b` error is a classical one.
It happens because your the BIOS of your newer machine is set to AHCI mode and your drive is missing the AHCI drivers.
The error occurs once Windows switches over to the preloaded drivers in the boot process.

Two solutions are possible:

1. Manipulating the old drive to include the required drivers
2. Changing the AHCI setting in your BIOS to something else (not RAID!), `IDE` or `legacy mode` as stated by cybernard in his answer.

But apart from that as far as I remember Windows XP does not respond in a flexible way to a new environment by updating all drivers.
I remember Acronis offering a duplicating software involving an extra feature that would update all drivers on the copy target.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to clone the hard drive to another hard drive so you don't wreck the original.**

While it is possible to connect the hard drive to another computer, and then attach the old registry, after that is the hard part.
After launching regedit select HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

[image: Load hive]

Change E: to the drive letter of the old PC.
So once you select "load hive", you will have to specify e:\windows\system32\config\system
Then it will ask for a name which can be anything.  I usually just use X because its short as possible.

After that you will have a HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/x which did not previously exists.

From there whatever you do to this key and its subkeys are part of the windows XP.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\x\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services
Contains the services.

However, from there I don't know how to switch to the default driver.

You error code refers to windows xp, not being able to access the hard drive.

Maybe if you could switch to an IDE or legacy mode in the BIOS you might be able to get somewhere.

I remember being able to delete a key, which emptied the device manager.  Then you use add new hardware wizard to restore plug and play functionality.
Then you wait as dozens of drivers are detected.

I think it was the HARDWARE key, but its been a decade so don't quote me on that.  Also this is why you want to have a back up of the original, so you can try breaking changes without risking the original.